# Filter in bucket key and doc_count in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which has multiple document. Now I want to write a query in elastic search which will allow me to filter on bucket key and doc_count

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

"aggregations": {
"genres": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
"sum_other_doc_count": 33,
"buckets": [
{
"key": "eone",
"doc_count": 5
}
,
{
"key": "etwo",
"doc_count": 2
}

]
}
}
```

I want to write query by which I can apply filter on key name and dpc count. Suppose I want to get result for which key is eone and doc count is 5 then I should only get the result of matching this critera

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `min_doc_count` like below,

```
{
    "aggs": {
      "genres": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "event.keyword",
          "min_doc_count": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

By using `filter` and `min_doc_count`

```
GET index_name/_search
  {
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "event.keyword": "eone"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "genres": {
        "terms": {
           "field": "event.keyword",
            "min_doc_count": 5
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

**OR** using `include` along with `min_doc_count` like below,

```
GET index_name/_search
  {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "genres": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "event.keyword",
          "min_doc_count": 5,
          "include" : "eone"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**See more:** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_4